Optional extra space at the end of rows in tabular?
Here's a minimal working example:
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}[5cm]{c | p{2cm} | c}
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\ 
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\[.5cm]
\hline
hello & Hello! This will be a longer bit of text. & hello \\[.5cm]
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\ 
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}

This produces:

Notice that there is extra space of .5cm specified at the end of table rows 2 and 3. However, this doesn't show up in the output in row 3 (presumably due to the longer text that runs onto multiple lines).
(1) I would love it if someone could explain to me, a novice, exactly why the space doesn't show up in row 3. And,
(2) What is the best way to match row 3 with row 2, so that they both have the same amount of vertical white space after the text?

The [5cm] is a syntax errror that is silently ignored, what did you intend it to do?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

@David Thanks for pointing this out. For some reason I was thinking that this would determine the total width of the table. I now see that at least one way to specify the total width of the table would be with the tabular* environment, using curly rather than square brackets.

With \\[0.5cm] you ask LaTeX that the depth of the line is at least 0.5cm more than the standard depth (the depth is how much goes below the baseline).
In your p multirow cell, the depth is a lot more than 0.5cm, because in this case the depth is determined by whatever goes after the first line, so nothing is added.
Use \vspace{0.5cm} instead, at the end of the cell.
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{c | p{2cm} | c}
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\[.5cm]
\hline
hello & Hello! This will be a longer bit of text.\vspace{0.5cm} & hello \\
\hline
hello & hello & hello \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Note that \begin{tabular}[5cm] does nothing meaningful and 5cm is just silently ignored.

